# Regex to pull out text between two strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the text from the [QOUTE] and [/QUOTE] but can seem to get it correctly. I'm just trying to pick it out and delete it. So I want to extract the text within as well as the actual HTML [QUOTE] parts. Just want to get rid of that entire code block via regex:

What I'm working with:

```
\[QUOTE(.+)|\[\/QUOTE]|
```

Text Example:

```
[QUOTE="", post: 1910681, member: 001""]
This is where the quote is located
[/QUOTE]
[URL unfurl=""true""]https://www.google.com[/URL]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming those tags can't be nested, you can use the following regex with the `s`ingle-line flag to match the tags and their content :

```
\[QUOTE\b.*?\[/QUOTE]
```

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/aNT1Yu/3).